# MongoDB projecting fields in $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo query that is something like this:

```
aggregate([

      { "$match": {"postId":postId}},
      { 
        "$project": {
        "f1":1,
        "f2":1,
        "f3":1, 
        "f4":1,
        "_id":1,
        "tempID" : { "$cond" : {<some condition>} }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {"_id" : "$tempID","maxVal" : { "$max": "$f2" }}
      }])
```

The problem is that I want the query to return all the fields in the original document. I have had to change the above query but the point is once I get to a $group only the fields that I specify are projected. I read that I can use the $first operator to include the fields back in at the $group phase. However I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this? Like if i can't use another $project and then nest the $group?

Comment: In your case there is no other option mainly because of the `$group` stage.

Comment: ok Styvane, thanks for the info was just wondering it this was the right way to do it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could push each item in to an array within the group projection eg

```
aggregate([

  { "$match": {"postId":postId}},
  { 
    "$project": {
    "f1":1,
    "f2":1,
    "f3":1, 
    "f4":1,
    "_id":1,
    "tempID" : { "$cond" : {<some condition>} }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
         "_id" : "$tempID",
        "maxVal" : { "$max": "$f2" }
        "items": {$push: {
    f1: "$f1",
    f2: "$f2",
    f3: "$f3", 
    f4: "$f4",
    _id: "$_id"}
    }
  }])
```